# How to remove content for specific page?

Tags: 7

I'm trying to remove some regions if the page is admin like this:

```
function mytheme_page_alter(&$page) { 
if (current_path() == 'admin') {
unset($page['content']);
unset($page['highlighted']);
} 
}
```

But it's not removing the contents and highlighted regions from `localhost/drupal/admin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont see any issue with the code. I tried the exact same code in my custom module and it works as expected.

Can you check what the base_url is in your case? I am guessing the current_path in your case is returned as drupal/admin and this is not matching the if condition you added. You may want to print the value for current_path() using the statement drupal_set_message(current_path()); to confirm the same.

Comment: you mean like this ? if (drupal_set_message(current_path()) == 'admin') {

Comment: No! drupal_set_message is used fir displaying the value in the message section of the page. You may want to try 
`code`
function mytheme_page_alter(&$page) { 
drupal_set_message(current_path());
if (current_path() == 'drupal/admin') {
unset($page['content']);
unset($page['highlighted']);
} 
}  
`code`

Comment: still unclear, where to put drupal_set_message ...

Comment: relook at my updated comment

Comment: Oh through the drupal_set ... I knew node/2 and tried that and removed...thanks... and how can I hide the logo

Comment: Is there any way that I could remove all but $page['login'] ???

Comment: Hi, again, thanks for your help.... another question: I would like to use drupal_set_message(current_path()); within my region so I tried this but not worked: print render $page['content']['system_main']['default_message']

Answer (score 0):

you may want to create a template file instead of making all these changes in a hook. Refer to this [link](https://drupal.org/node/1089656) for more details.